# How to change drawable of image button if two edit text fields are not empty

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have looked over the recommended similar questions and tried many different approaches but so far they haven't worked and I am not sure why. Maybe I implemented them wrong but unsure.

What I am trying to do is change the drawable of a button to a brighter color if two Edittext fields both go from being empty to having text in them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="My email and password are"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailReg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_lightitalic"
        android:hint="email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordReg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_lightitalic"
        android:inputType="textWebPassword"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:text="Clicking 'Continue' will send a verification email to the address above. This will be used to log you in at future dates." />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/registerReg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

and the activity:

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //VARIABLES

    private ImageButton mRegister;

    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPassword;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener fireBaseAuthStateListener;

    private DatabaseReference userRef;

    String emailStr;
    String passwordStr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        //VARIABLE IDS

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailReg);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordReg);
        mRegister = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.registerReg);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    emailStr = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                }
            }
        });

        mPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    passwordStr = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                }
            }
        });


        changeButtonDrawable(emailStr, passwordStr);


        //REGISTER BUTTON

            mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            firebaseUtility fU = new firebaseUtility();

                            String currentUserId = fU.getUserIdString();
                            DatabaseReference userRef = fU.getUserDatabaseRef(currentUserId);

                            Map userInfo = new HashMap();

                            userInfo.put("email", email);
                            userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", "default");

                            userRef.updateChildren(userInfo);

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }
                        }

                    });

                }
            });

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, NameAgeZipActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void changeButtonDrawable (String email, String password){
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            mRegister.setImageResource(R.drawable.continue_btn_grey_on_grey);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mRegister.setImageResource(R.drawable.continue_btn_white_on_purple);
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, the ImageButton should change to the drawable continue_btn_white_on_purple if there is text in both fields, but right now it just stays grey. Been trying to figure this out for a while. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make a drawable file for your button like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <!--if button is disabled it will show this color-->
            <solid android:color="@color/disabledBtnBg" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now set it to your button

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/primary_btn_bg"
    ...
/>
```

then go to your Java file and Add this :

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
    mRegister. mVerifyBtn.setEnabled(false);
else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
    mRegister. mVerifyBtn.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more real time-ish approach is to use TextChangedListener

```
mEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() != 0 && mPassword.getText().toString().length != 0) { 
            mRegister.setImageResource(R.drawable.continue_btn_grey_on_grey);
        } else {
            mRegister.setImageResource(R.drawable.continue_btn_white_on_purple);
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});

mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() != 0 && mEmail.getText().toString().length != 0) { 
            mRegister.setImageResource(R.drawable.continue_btn_grey_on_grey);
        } else {
            mRegister.setImageResource(R.drawable.continue_btn_white_on_purple);
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

So the changes on imageButton reflects instantly

Comment: Sorry the logic might be the other way around (I'm not sure) but you can play with it and see if it works.